# Issue with the load function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, formwizard, jquery-form-wizard

I have 2 files: `users.php` and `form.php`.

I use the file `users.php` to show the users from a database. I am also using the jQuery function `load()` to load the login form  from `form.php`.

I put the jQuery library in the header of `login.php` . In `form.php` I have some jQuery functions so I have to put the jQuery library in it also.

The problem  is when I use the `$("#loginForm").load("form.php")` the jQuery get all the libraries of `form.php`

form.php :

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script> 

<script src="js/ui/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<!-- Jquery form wizard -->
<script src="js/formWizard/jquery.form.js"></script>    
<script src="js/formWizard/jquery.validate.js"></script>    
<script src="js/formWizard/bbq.js"></script>  
<script src="js/formWizard/jquery.form.wizard.js"></script>
<form method="post" >
    ...
</form>
```

user.php

```
<div id="loginForm"> 
</div>
```

And in the header of `user.php` there are these scripts files above

Comment: There is a little information...

Comment: Show us the complete html of form.php please.

Comment: Could you be more specific with what you're loading, so you skip any scripts? For example: `$('#loginForm').load('form.php #container');`

Comment: I did include the code above it starts with <div id="loginForm">

Comment: @ahren no i don't wanna to skip because if I skip the scripts the effects won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on your problem but it sounds like your jQuery libraries are loading in twice. Once from user.php and once from form.php

To stop this happening, you could try extracting the libraries from user.php and form.php to one common header file (header.php). then use

```
require_once('header.php');
```

function to ensure the file is loaded only once.

Comment: Thanks..back then I haven't a lot of experience in jQuery